# error while dereferencing pointer to type to the next value

Tags: c, pointers

This code should have brought me a printed value of 7. As i am have declared integer ***i=5*** which allocates 4 bytes in memory and integer ***myInt*** which also allocates **4 bytes** next to the **int i**. Then i declared a pointer to store the location/address of the **int i**. But when I add 1 integer to the pointer or i's location which means 4bytes to pointer location of **i** and then dereference it. I don't get the **7 which i stored in myInt** rather i get some value as 243423(something like this)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
int i=5;
int myInt=7;
int *pointer = &i;

printf("%i\n", *(pointer+1));
getch();
}
```

Comment: That's undefined behavior, you can't rely on anything sensible happening when you dereference `(&i)+1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare "i" and and "myInt" as static and you will get your expected behaviour.

Note 1: This kind of design is only useful for didactic purposes;
Note 2: The correct way to store these values in order to access using pointers is to use an vector.

Comment: How to declare them as static could you please post the code? Also please explain that correct way : how to use access a pointer using vector?

Comment: int i=5; ---> static int i=5;
int myInt=7; ---> static int myInt=7

Comment: Yaa it got the answer but whats this static does or means?  Also you were saying something about the vector could you provide me a link where i can read? **accessing pointers using vectors**

Comment: Your first declaration used stack to store the variables and it does not guarantee that variables are stored sequentially due the fact that      fundamental machine instructions can use stack to store temporally data or references as well. Therefore, static variables are stored at the program data region at the very same sequence as you declare and persists till the end of your application. due this fact the changed (using static) code worked.

Answer (score 2):

`pointer` is a different address location pointing to `i`, now when you add `+1` a `sizeof(int)` it addresses next location of `pointer` but not second stack variable `myInt`.

```
 pointer
+-------+               +------+
| 0x100 | -----> 0x100  |  5   |
+-------+               +------+
  0x300          0x104  |  7   |
                        +------+
```

A simple memory can be as above, both local variables `i` & `myInt` can store in stack in contiguous  memory locations. But you made `pointer` to point to `i` and `pointer` itself stored in address location `0x300`. Now when you dereference next memory location of `pointer` which doesn't point to `myInt` rather some other memory location which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @SunEric can you have a look at this video at time: 1:52 [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQ2ZiXzJjE&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810) as tell if its correct?

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan Tutor in the video took an example storing variables sequentially but its not guaranteed that memory allocation is continuous leading to Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Ok thanks @SunEric great help but is their any permanent solution to this problem. So i can do pointer maths easily.

Comment: how to use pointer maths to point to `myInt` location and printout **7** with the help of simple algebra with *pointer? Is it possible?

Comment: I suggest you to understand how compiler allocates memory in different scenarios and how it operates on them. Best to learn this first, which will answer you question/doubt and get clarified by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm,  memory allocation isnt always continuum.
*(pointer+1) points to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0):

I can see where you're going, but you're getting tripped up by a misunderstanding.

If you allocate an array, the elements of the array **will** be placed next to each other, and things will work the way you're expecting:

```
int foo[] = { 4, 3, 2, 1 };
int* i = foo;
printf("%d\n", *i);
printf("%d\n", *(i + 1));
```

Likewise, if you `malloc` a block of memory, and then put objects next to each other in that memory, you can use pointer arithmetic the way you're expecting.

However, if you allocate two objects at about the same time, the language does not promise to put them next to each other in memory.  There is no reason for pointer arithmetic to work unless you tell the compiler "I want to allocate these objects next to each other."  You do that by creating an array, or allocating a block of memory.

---

A compiler is allowed to lay out memory as described in the video, but it's not required to. Using the variables from the video and the original question, the compiler is allowed to notice that you never do anything with `myInt` and optimize it away. It's also allowed to notice that `myInt` never changes and output a constant which can be allocated in a different memory area. It might decide to allocate all local variables contiguously on the stack, but in a different order than what appears in the source code (perhaps doing so allows for better use of RAM).

Even in cases where it puts `i` and `myInt` next to each other, on some platforms `i` will have the lower address and on other platforms `myInt` will. The compiler has enough flexibility that if you want the variables allocated next to each other, you need to make that clear.

Comment: could you please have a look at this video at 1:31 above? and tell me if its correct 
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jQ2ZiXzJjE&list=PL0170B6E7DD6D8810)